# remove comma from number and store in sqlite and retrieve data from sqlite and display it with comma

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios6

I have following numbers which has to be inserted into sqlite db and comma needs to be removed and decimal point needs to remain while inserting into sqlite db.

While retrieving I need to display the value with comma at exact position in ios6.Please guide me I am noob to sqlite and iOS.Thanks in Advance.Please treat this question as a common question for beginners to enter data into sqlite db.Thanks again.

```
Price
377,245.67
5,104,245.00
23,332.98
126,875.21
5,112,225.14
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to remove commas and get an NSNumber from string,

```
NSNumber *numberObj = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""] floatValue]];
```

Then to get the string with comma in number,

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];
NSString *formattedString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:floatNumber]];
```

For more details check [NSNumberFormatter Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Hi ACB.Thanks for the answer .But does it take care of Decimal points in the number displayed above.

Comment: Hi ACB I tried your answer but 
    **NSString *string=@"5,112,225.14";    
NSNumber *numberObj = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""] floatValue]]; 
 NSLog(@"number = %@", numberObj);** I get : **number = 5112225**   The decimal points and the nuber after that is missing.Please help.

Comment: @JacobWood, Are you sure you are using `[formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:`? You might be using an `numberWithInteger` instead of `float`. That is why you are getting it like that. Please copy paste it as it is.

Comment: I used     
    **NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; // this line is important!
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:5];

    
    NSString *formatted = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:2000000.81234]];
        
     NSLog(@"number = %@", formatted);**
and it worked.

Comment: Nice to know that. Merry Xmas.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy. You can use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` to remove commas before insertion. After you retrieve, just insert comma on each fourth place starting from the end.

Comment: Thanks Mike.Is there function in iOS 6 which puts comma on fourth place by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you perform any specific numerical operations on that field directly? If not, you can store them and retrieve them as strings and then convert string to integers directly.

Comment: Thanks Akshay but is there any function which puts comma to price by itself in ios 6.